# get the selected itemssource binding value on selectedindexchanged on picker xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Picker in xamarin forms. I am binding the below class to Picker:

```
public string FieldCode{get; set; }
public string FieldValue{get; set; }
```

The Picker is like below:

```
<Picker Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="pkrMvmtCat" Style="{StaticResource WOFormPicker}" Title="Select" ItemsSource="{Binding FieldCode}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding FieldValue}" SelectedIndexChanged="pkrMvmtCat_SelectedIndexChanged"></Picker>
```

I want to get the FieldCode value, when i change the picker index.

Please me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.. Because you set the `ItemsSource` to a single string value? This should be a list of values. Then set the `SelectedItem` to a property where you want to have the new selected value and bind to it with a two-way binding.

Comment: I want the selected FieldCode value on pkrMvmtCat_SelectedIndexChanged.

Comment: Compare the index coming in through the event with the collection that you bind as an item source to the picker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to listen to the event, and then cast the selected item from the list. Here is an example:

```
void OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var picker = (Picker)sender;
  int selectedIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;

  if (selectedIndex != -1)
  {
    var field = (string)picker.ItemsSource[selectedIndex];
  }
}
```

Comment: it is working... Thank you Bruno. Just Edited like "var field = (string)picker.ItemsSource[selectedIndex] as <ClassName>;"